Calculus for the practical man Chapter 4, problem 8
One end of a wire wound on a reel is fastened to the top of a pole 35 feet high; two men holding the reel on a rod on their shoulders five feet above the level ground walk away from the pole at the rate of 5 miles an hour (7 and 1/3 ft/sec), keeping the wire straight. How far are they from the pole when the wire is unwinding at the rate of one mile an hour? (1.467 ft/sec)

My working out:
I used a triangle, cut the 35 feet to 30 feet due to their heights, and made dy/dt = 1.467 ft and dx/dt = 7.33 ft/sec. My solution was 5.2 ft/sec and the book says it's 6.1 ft/sec. What am I doing wrong? My work is below hope it helps, I'm not too familiar with the website either. Sorry!


What are your equations? The ground is level, why do you have any $dy/dt$?

To find the distance would be x = sqrt(y^(2)-30^(2)) and that should get you the distance. I am new to calculus as well so I've only learnt rates and derivatibes

The dy/dt is the 1 mile an hour unwinding

Edit your post to include your equations and use mathjax formatting and we will help you fix your approach

I included an image of my working

If you post more questions here, please use mathjax formatting, it's easy to do, hit "Edit" on my post and you'll see how numbers, variables, etc are included in "$". Your posts will risk being closed otherwise.

The equations go off the rails about halfway down the picture, it's hard to tell why with the scribbling and unusual notation, here is a clean take:
$L=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
with $x$ the horizontal, $y$ the vertical, and $L$ the length of line on the diagonal. We are given $y=30$, $dy/dt=0$, $dx/dt=5$, and we wish to find $x$ when $dL/dt=1$.
$dL/dt=(1/2)(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}(2x)(dx/dt)=(x)(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}(dx/dt)$
Substituting in our needed values:
$\frac{dL}{dt}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{dx}{dt}$
$1=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(5)$
$\frac{1}{25}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+30^2}$
$24x^2=30^2 \rightarrow x=\frac{15}{\sqrt{6}} \approx 6.2$
Edit: note that since the rates cancel, we can mix and match units of mph (for rates) and feet (for position) and obtain the x-position in convenient units (ft) without doing any conversions to ft/s.

Thankyou, I appreciate the effort put in to help my bad problem solving!
